# Как добавить полигоны из geoQuery на карту и проверить точку?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Реализован пример из документации (Проверка адреса на попадание в зону доставки), но с изменениями. В моём случае иначе поступают данные, работать нужно с тем, что есть. 
Собираю json feature collection, аналогичный примеру. 
Проблемы возникает сразу 2:

1.Не добавляются на карту сами полигоны

2.При поиске методом searchContaining вылетает
 ошибка "Cannot read property '0' of null"

Код на [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yqasoy46lcNvcIE7bWKp?p=preview)'е

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [30.264981955459618, 59.9567962610097],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: ['zoomControl']
  });

  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([60.014596, 30.393529], {}, {
    preset: 'islands#redCircleIcon'
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark)

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      alert('ошибка: ' + (xhr.status ? xhr.statusText : 'запрос не удался'));
      return;
    }

    xhrResult = xhr.responseText;
    var routesData = JSON.parse(xhrResult)

    var jsonData = {
      'type': "FeatureCollection",
      'features': []
    };

    for (var newPolygon of routesData) {
      var coords = JSON.parse(newPolygon.MapArea);

      if (coords && newPolygon.Id > 0) {
        jsonData.features.push({
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": newPolygon.Id,
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": coords
          },
          "options": {
            "strokeColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "fillColor": newPolygon.Color,
            "fillOpacity": 0.4
          },
          "properties": {
            "name": newPolygon.Name + " " + newPolygon.Description
          }
        })
      }

    }


    var deliveryZones = ymaps.geoQuery(jsonData).addToMap(myMap);

    var targetZone = deliveryZones.searchContaining(myPlacemark)

    console.log(targetZone);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"1.Не добавляются на карту сами полигоны"
Добавляются, просто у вас стоит `coordorder=longlat` и поэтому они добавляются в Иране https://plnkr.co/edit/TWaSYI8PAjyjK5BfDfnS?p=preview
Уберите coordorder=longlat в подключении.
"2.При поиске методом searchContaining вылетает ошибка "Cannot read property '0' of null""
У какого-то полигона плохие координаты, я поставил, чтобы не все полигоны добавлялись на карту и всё начало работать.
https://plnkr.co/edit/n9KI4iS6HrVpaFeZ2RFC?p=preview